# Http Client Post Method

Tags: java, httpclient

How can I post username and password for `Linked In` using http client in java. In Linked we found
Some Parameter like:

```
{"source_app", ""},
{"session_key", session_key},
{"session_password", session_password},
{"signin", "Sign%20In"},
{"session_redirect", ""},
{"csrfToken", csrfToken},
{"sourceAlias", sourceAlias}
```

And also how to maintain Cookies in post httpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I think official documentation of `httpclient` covers how to `POST` data [Documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) and how to  handle cookies [Cookie httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html)

This is also a handy tutorial [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html). Take a loook at these sites/tutorials and write some code for your application, than ask some specific question for the problem you are facing.

Comment: how to apply post for linkedIn login.

Comment: above we write some parameter for posting and also need to maintain cookies.So what is the process to maintain cookies.